# $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] not showing Facebook page full url

Tags: php, facebook, http-referer

I'm trying to use `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` to get the referer page URL on one of my forms.

```
$form['values'][] = htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

It happens that when the referer is my facebook page, I only get **Referer page:** `https://l.facebook.com/` and not the full URL of my facebook page

Any ideias why?

Comment: `print_r($_SERVER)` and choose desired index. `HTTP_REFERER` seems to be different from your desired value.

Comment: @AksenP nothing on `print_r($_SERVER)` show's an index with my facebook page URL

Comment: _“Any ideas why?”_ - because Facebook deliberately implemented it this way, to better protect user privacy. https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-security/link-shim-protecting-the-people-who-use-facebook-from-malicious-urls/10150492832835766/

Comment: @04FS any workarounds?

Comment: If there were any workarounds to this, it would mean Facebook would have done a poor job on their stated goal regarding this to begin with … (And btw., I hope you don’t think this is a Facebook-only problem to begin with? _Any other site_ you try to get this info from, might just tell the user’s browser to send only partial referrer info, or none at all - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referrer-Policy)

Comment: ...and the PHP docs on `HTTP_REFERER` says: `This is set by the user agent. Not all user agents will set this, and some provide the ability to modify HTTP_REFERER as a feature. In short, it cannot really be trusted.`